# Concrete porches pulling away from home and cracking

Tags: concrete, deck, stairs, construction, porch

I have an 1940'sish home with old concrete porches (x3) they are cracking, chipping, and pulling away from the home. Would I be able to repair them? If not could I build a deck over them (wooden)? I would prefer to build stairs for the time being as I am low on funds for a deck so that would be the best option, would that be possible? They are not solid concrete, filled in with cinder blocks and rocks. 
thank you!

Comment: Some photos would be helpful. It's difficult to properly asses the situation, without being able to see what's going on.

Comment: Nightmare land. There are a lot of people who think you can just pour a big block of concrete on the ground and it will stay that way forever. As you are discovering, that is not true.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot repair them. If a large concrete structure is falling apart, it means the foundation is not good. Putting a deck over it to hide the disaster is probably a good idea. Obviously, you should make footings below the frost line for your deck, unless you want the same thing to happen to it.

Personally I would probably build the deck and then sell the house and try to distract potential buyers as much as possible.

Comment: Remind me not to buy a house from you. ;-)

Comment: I have seen companies drill through concrete, dig out foot holes, mudjack the footings and the porch, and apply an epoxy coating over the whole thing.  That isn't repairing them?